# Correct a fisheyed picture using Hugin

Tags: wide-angle, distortion, fisheye, hugin

I've got a *Olympus Body Cap* 9mm fisheye lens for my *Panasonic DMC-GM1* camera. I was told to use Hugin to correct the fisheyed pictures taken with that lens.

When I import my pictures into Hugin, it asks me for the parameters of the lens:

[image]

I guess I have to enter 9mm into focal length, but what about the other fields?

Furthermore, which features do I have to use afterwards to correct my images? All I tried resulted in even more fisheyier pictures.

Is Hugin even the right tool to do what I want? If no, what other tool should I use? I'm running Linux, so Photoshop is not an option.

Comment: You might change the question title to 'How do I correct fisheye distortion **using Linux**' to make clearer this is not a duplicate. And I just noticed the Darktable site I linked to is down, so use the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4SEtr6bZi4cJ:www.darktable.org/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu) for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following instructions which helped me achieve what I was looking for:

- http://m43photo.blogspot.de/2012/03/defishing-fisheye-images.html
- http://m43photo.blogspot.de/2014/07/olympus-9mm-fisheye-vs-rectilinear.html

For my lens I found the following parameters useful:

- Lens type: Full frame Fisheye
- Focal length: 9mm
- Focal length multiplier: 2.2
- Projection: architectural

Comment: Why 2.2 for focal length multiplier? Micro 4/3 has a crop factor (or focal length multiplier) of 2.0, so probably best to set that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I just tried some values, and 2.2 seemed to get me the best results.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Darktable lens correction module]
Try using [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) instead. The 'lens correction' module shown above should help remove the fisheye effect. If your lens is in the database it can automatically make the correction, or if not you may adjust manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Darktable doesn't know my camera nor the lens, and somehow I didn't manage to set the values manually. How can I do that?